# How to create a nested model in kendo-mvvm

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mvvm

Consider the following JSON values:

```
[
{
    OrderId: 1,
    OrderName: 'order 1'
    OrderItems: [
        {
            ProductId: 1,
            ProductName: "sample name"
        },
        {
            ProductId: 2,
            ProductName: "sample name 2"
        }
}
}
]
```

I am defining a model with this structure:

```
var model = kendo.data.Model.define({
    id: "OrderId",
    fields: {
        OrderId: {
                type: "number",
                editable: false
        },

        OrderName: {
                type: "string",
                editable: false
        },

        OrderItems: {
            ??????????????
        }
    }
});
```

Is it possible to define a model in such a way that we can change the `OrderItems` during the CRUD operation?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're mixing column definitions for your controls and the model for you orders. This simplified model will help you get started with the array of order items.

```
var model = kendo.data.Model.define(
{
    "Order": {
        "OrderId": 12345,
        "OrderName": "myname",
        "OrderItems": [{
            "ProductId": 1,
            "ProductName": "sample name"
        }, {
            "ProductId": 2,
            "ProductName": "another product"
        }]
    }
}
)
```

You can iterate through the model.Order.OrderItems collection with $.each